# Multiple source web audio and gain

Tags: web

I'm new to the web-audio api, and sound design in general. So this will probably be a noob question.

I'm playing multiple tracks using the `createBufferSource()`. To set the gain on the tracks, I'm also using the `createGain()` function of the audio api.

Do I need to **change the gain on the tracks according to the number of tracks** playing to keep the overall volume level? In other words, is the overall volume higher depending on how many tracks are playing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should go on Stackoverflow

Comment: Ok. Can I move this, or should a moderator do it?

Comment: This has been flagged so a moderator will do it but you still can close the subject and paste it on the appropriate platform. Best.

Comment: I question whether this should be moved. It is definitely a sound question. The fact that the OP is working with code rather than a mouse and windows is irrelevant to the question. It’s still about sound design with multichannel audio and gain, which programmers may not know about, but sound designers do. Sound designers write code, graphic designers write code, and that is not necessarily programming — it’s still sound design and graphic design.

Comment: @SimonW I agree; this is fundamentally a question about sound. Maybe too basic for SDSE though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the additional sounds will add to the master output gain. You need to leave headroom and/or monitor the levels.

You can find out more about it here:

[Metering | Web Audio API by Boris Smus](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch03.html#s03_4)

The above book is highly recommended.